# Get multiple selected cell values in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which i can select multiple cells and after selection i would like to get column and row value from every selected cell.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="our_table">
                                <thead style="background-color: #393a44;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>MON</th>
                                        <th>TUE</th>
                                        <th>WED</th>
                                        <th>THU</th>
                                        <th>FRI</th>
                                        <th>SAT</th>
                                        <th>SUN</th>
                                    </tr>



                                </thead>



                                <tr>
                                    <td>00h</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
      <tr>
                                    <td>01h</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
      <tr>
                                    <td>02h</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
      <tr>
                                    <td>03h</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
```

Show all selected

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sakonja/htzczx5x/)

When i select some cells in table on button click i would like to get text from column and row for all selected cells.

If i select cells monday 0h and 1h and tuesday 0h result when i click button would be 0h monday,1h monday, 0h tuesday

Comment: What is your question? All you have stated is what you are wanting to do, not what problems you have accomplishing it. Keep in mind we aren't here to be a code writing service but will gladly help with specific problems

Comment: well my problem was not knowing how to archive that :). I know ppl are not here to write code but i did get answers and when i will be better at this i will sure help someone too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .map() and index based lookup

```
 $('#Spremi').click(function(){
     var $heads = $('#our_table thead th');
     var array = $('#our_table td.highlighted').map(function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         return $this.parent().children().eq(0).text() + ' ' + $heads.eq($this.index()).text();
     }).get()
     console.log(array)
 })
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/86a9s7dd/)

Comment: Thanks guys i really didnt know how to archive that a all of you helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$("#Spremi").click(function(){

    $(".highlighted").each(function(){
    var day= $("#our_table tr th").eq($(this).index()).text();
        var hour= $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text();
        alert(day + hour);
    });
});
```

You can loop through each highlighted elements with `.each()`. Then take the index of the current td, find corresponding heading using that index.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoship/htzczx5x/10/)

Comment: Thanks guys i really didnt know how to archive that a all of you helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can iterate over all highlighted `td`s and find its corresponding hour and week day label using `closest()`

```
$('#Spremi').click(function(){
     var str = "";
     $('#our_table tr td.highlighted').each(function(){
         if($(this).text().trim()=='')
         {
            var index = $(this).index();
            // get hour label
            str += $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
            //get week day label
            str = str + 
                 $(this).closest('table').find('tr:first th:eq('+index+')').text(); 
                 + ", ";
           }             
      });   
      alert(str);
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/htzczx5x/13/)**

Comment: Thanks guys i really didnt know how to archive that a all of you helped me :)